# Trouble rendering MathJax equations wrapped in span tags

Tags: django, latex, ckeditor, mathjax

I'm trying to render math equations in my template using Django, along with [CKEditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor). When I render my math equation, in inspect element, it looks like this:

```
<p><span class="mathjax-latex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p></p>
```

However, even with the MathJax scripts enabled, the formula doesn't render when I go look at it. Here is my MathJax script in the template:

```
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    showProcessingMessages: false, //Close js loading process information
    messageStyle: "none", //Do not display information
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath:  [ ["$", "$"] ], //In-line formula selection$
        displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"] ], //The formula selection in the paragraph$$
        skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre','code','a'], //Avoid certain tags
        ignoreClass:"comment-content", //Avoid tags containing the Class
        processClass: "mathjax-latex",
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {
        availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], //Optional font
        showMathMenu: false //Close the right-click menu display
    }
});
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

What do I need to do to render math equations with the `span` tags attached?

Answer (score 0):

Latex has two math modes, inline mode and display mode. The first is used to delimit math that should be displayed "where it is" (for example in the middle of a sentence) whereas the latter is used to delimit math that should be displayed in a more standalone and "fancy" way (in its own paragraph and centered).

In the input configuration that you supply, you tell MathJax to use `$` to delimit inline math and `$$` to delimit display math.

```
    inlineMath:  [ ["$", "$"] ], //In-line formula selection$
    displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"] ], //The formula selection in the paragraph$$
```

These delimiters are **VERY** common to use, albeit not the defaults. In fact, `\(` and `\)` is the default for inline math, which you also use in your example.

Because you have told MathJax to use `$` as a delimiter, it won't recognize the math you supply as something that needs to be processed, so it skips it and the math remains non-typeset. Switch to using the delimiter `$` that you supplied, and it will work.

Here is a working sandbox with only this change: https://codesandbox.io/s/mathjax-jw4py